# Getting NSTextField by tag number?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I've got a bunch of NSTextFields on a window (tagged 1-8) and I'm wondering if it's possible to access each individual text field programatically by its *tag number* so I can then get/set its value?

I'm a newbie and while I know how to access these fields by name, doing it by tag number will make things an awful lot simpler for what I'm trying to achieve in this particular instance.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: “… I know how to access these fields by name…” You mean through your outlet variables. Most Cocoa classes (including NSTextField) don't let you name their instances, and even those that do usually don't let you look up an instance by name.

Comment: Correct. I did mean through their outlet variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
the_fourth_textview = [the_superview_containing_all_textfields viewWithTag:4];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Kenny :-) Unfortunately I'm not up to speed yet on subviews and superviews etc. so I wasn't able to successfully translate the above pseudocode into code that works...

I tried:

    NSTextView *fieldToChange;
    fieldToChange = [[self superview] viewWithTag:4];

but this is obviously wrong. By the way, the window belongs to an NSWindowController subclass within my (NSObject) app if that helps.

Comment: If you don't know which is the superview, just put the window object there.

Comment: All fixed now Kenny! Appreciate your help :-)

Comment: unknown: Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer. (Also, NSTextView and NSTextField are different classes.)